# Vue: Use Vuex store outside of component without Import Statements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, ecmascript-5

In Vue 2/3, and in an ES6 environment when I want to access a Vuex store in an external JS file (outside of the component), I would normally use something like this:

```js
// example.js

import { store } from '../store/index';

console.log(store.state.currentUser);
```

This works great, however, in my current environment *(Rails 5 without webpack)*, we can't use `import` statements at all.

**Question: Is there any way, in regular ES5 JavaScript, to access Vuex stores outside of components?**

It's worth noting that I've got a successful setup of Vuex going on our frontend, we just can't access it outside of our defined Vue components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Rails setup, I have this:

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/lib/vuex/store.js

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    activity: activityStore,
  }
});
```

```js
// application.js

//= require vue/dist/vue.min
//= require vuex/dist/vuex.min.js

$(document).ready(function () {

  Vue.use(Vuex);

});
```

**In this instance, `store` is just a global javascript object. Use it the same as you would any other JS object.**

As long as you're inside a JS file that is properly compiled, and your base Vue is installed properly, you can just do `store.state.activity.activities`, or if you have mutations, `store.commit('myMutation', 'Hello test')`.

My specific example was a huge function calling a webhook. The webhook can take a while, and I want to send messages to the user as I get new messages.

Example:

```js
// webhook.js

async webhookFunction() {
  // new message recieved
  store.commit('newActivity', 'Your object has been updated');
}
```

Comment: You'll naturally have the problem that global variables bring. If any other script defines `store` (which is a popular name), there will be a conflict.